# GPU out of memory in AI implementation for image editing

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am working recently with an AI for image editing.
It worked flawlessly for several months, but out of nowhere it has stopped working. I share with you the code I use:

```
import torch
from PIL import Image
import mediapy as media
import transformers
from diffusers import StableDiffusionXLImg2ImgPipeline

pipe = StableDiffusionXLImg2ImgPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    use_safetensors=True,
).to("cuda")

# Parameters selection
url = "C:\images\instru_per8_1.png"
save_path = "C:\images\editada\instru_per8.png"
prompt = "HD, circular, realistic polished woode"
n_prompt = "blurry, robot-like texture, disfigured, shadow, snow"
img_strength = 0.3  # Consistency with the original image. Values from 0 to 1, where 0 is         identical and 1 is very different.
n_steps = 25  # Values from 1 to 100; 25 is recommended. Number of samplings for transforming     noise into an image.
creativity = 10  # Values from 2 to 20; 7-12 is recommended. The higher the value, the more the     image sticks to a given text input.

init_image = Image.open(url)
image = pipe(
    prompt=prompt,
    image=init_image,
    negative_prompt=n_prompt,
    strength=img_strength,
    num_inference_steps=n_steps,
    guidance_scale=creativity
).images[0]

image.save(save_path)
del image`
```

And the error is: "torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.00 GiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 12.00 GiB of which 0 bytes is free. Of the allocated memory 9.88 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 68.34 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"

I used to use a Google Colab implementation, I have migrated to visual studio to use a computer with much more capacity than the Colab environment. The error is the same in both implementations. I also tried reducing the image resolution, and it seemed to make more progress in the process, but it just failed the same way.

Comment: Clearly, you don't have enough available VRAM. Try 1.5GiB or just 1 GiB